# What is HeapTrim in the means of ART

Tags: android, android-runtime

I have a `RecyclerView` which displays some items including `Bitmaps` that can be local or loaded from a remote path. The `RecyclerView` performs well, and the amounts of memory being freed by the GC seem to be normal.

Once I noticed the following in the LogCat:

```
I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 10.026ms for cause HeapTrim
```

I haven't seen this message on Dalvik and this is the first time I see it on ART. After some googling I haven't found anything that would explain this log.

What exactly does this message mean? Does it point out some performance/memory issues? Do I need to pay attention/try to improve the memory management?

Comment: strange no answer till now

Comment: @MuhammadBabar yep. Btw, I still haven't found out the answer

Comment: I have same issue. Not sure what is going on...